# Does replying to an e-mail that was forwarded include the original sender in the conversation?

Tags: gmail

I am using Gmail. I received an e-mail from A, forwarded it to B, and then replied to the A e-mail. Does A see my conversation with B about A email?

Answer (score 3):

No. The only way they would see it is if you cc them in the forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

When you forward an email, GMail basically duplicates the email and puts this text in front:

---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: ...
Date: The date the email was sent (not the fowarded email)
Subject: The subject of the email that was sent to you
To: Your email

If you want, you can just remove this section of the email.